# How to set the font_path in wordcloud while using Google-colaboratory?

Tags: python, fonts, google-colaboratory, word-cloud

I'm trying to use Arial font in my word cloud through this code however it couldn't find the font_path and returns an error:

> This code works well in Jupyter(Anaconda) but not in Google-Colab.

The only thing needs to be solved is what path should I enter for `font_path` in Google-Colab.
I have also tried: `font_path='/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf'`
and received the same error

input:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='arial',stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white", max_font_size=50, max_words=100).generate(txt)
```

output:

> cannot open resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uploaded the font to my google-drive and used this code which worked:

`wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/drive/My Drive/ARIAL.TTF',stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white", max_font_size=50, max_words=100).generate(txt)`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, you need to specify the path in Google Colab. I did the following steps:

1. Upload the TTF file in Google Colab. (This will require you to upload files again and again after restarting the runtime).
2. After uploading the font file, click on the three dots and select "Copy Path".
3. In the font_path attribute, paste the path:

   `wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path="/Arial-Regular.ttf",width = 500, height = 500, background_color='black',colormap='Set2',random_state=5).generate(text)`